# Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $F$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question: Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. Let $F$ be the set of all functions $f: S \to S$. Let $R$ be the relation on $F$ defined by

For any $f, g \in F$, $fRg$ if and only if $f (1) + f (2) = g (1) + g (2)$.

Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $F$.

I understand that to do this we must prove that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. I'm just having trouble using the definitions of these 3 properties to make an actual proof.

Comment: Please use MathJax in future :)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try and get you started:

### Reflexivity:

Let $f\in F$. Then $f(1)+f(2)=\dots$.

*You need $f$ in $g$'s place.*

### Symmetry:

Let $f,g\in F$. Then we have

$$\begin{align}
fRg &\iff f(1)+f(2)=g(1)+g(2) \\
&\iff g(1)+g(2)=f(1)+f(2)\quad\text{ (by symmetry of equality)} \\
&\iff \dots
\end{align}$$

*You need to conclude $gRf$ (preferably using "if and only if" statements, although implication is sufficient).*

### Transitivity:

Let $f, g,h\in F$ with $fRg$ and $gRh$. Then, by definition of $R$, we have $f(1)+f(2)=g(1)+g(2)$ and $g(1)+g(2)=\dots$

*You need to conclude that $fRh$.*

Answer (score 2):

Reflexivity: For all $f \in F$, we have $f(1)+f(2)=f(1)+f(2)$ so $f R f$

symmetric: Let $f, g \in F$ and $fRg$, then  $f(1)+f(2)=g(1)+g(2) \Rightarrow g(1)+g(2)=f(1)+f(2) \Rightarrow g R f$

Transitivity: Let $f,g,h \in F$ and $f R g$ and $g R h$ then $f(1)+f(2)=g(1)+g(2)$ and $g(1)+g(2)=h(1)+h(2)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(1)+f(2)=h(1)+h(2) \Rightarrow f R h.$

So $R$ is an equivalence relation on $F$.

Comment: NB: It's "equivalence relation", not "equivalent relation".

Comment: Ah thank you for correcting me!

Comment: You're welcome :)